# Whole sections of code are not activating. Believe it may have to do with typecasting

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, instanceof

I'm writing some code that is supposed to print out a list of books that fit a criteria. But the problem is that the books the code gets to the point where the loop that checks and prints out matches starts. Then just skips over the whole loop. I tested the loop to see if it was runing at all and it doesn't seem to be.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int count;
    count = 0;

    Book bookList [] = new Book[100];

    File file = new File("books.txt");                                  //assigns file
    Scanner textScan = new Scanner(file);                               //opens scanner to file

    do{
        String newType = textScan.nextLine();
        if(newType.equals("TradeBook")){
            bookList[count] =
                    new Tradebook(textScan.next(), textScan.next(),
                            textScan.nextInt(), textScan.nextDouble(), textScan.next());

        }
        else if(newType.equals("TextBook")){
            bookList[count] =
                    new Textbook(textScan.next(), textScan.next(),
                            textScan.nextInt(), textScan.nextDouble(), textScan.next());
        }
        count++;
    }while(textScan.hasNextLine());
    textScan.close();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your Major: ");
    String major = scan.next();

    String courseList [] = new String[10];
    count = 0;
    int sentinal = 0;
    do{
    System.out.println("Enter a course name: (xxx to quit): ");
    String temp = scan.next();
    if(temp.equals("xxx")||temp.equals("XXX")){
        sentinal = 1;
    }
    else{
    courseList[count] = temp;
    count++;
    }
    }while (sentinal != 1);

    scan.close();

    double retailSum = 0;
    double bookPrice = 0;
    System.out.println("List of textbooks: ");

    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();  //POST: converts numbers into currency form

    for(int n = 0; n<11; n++){
        for (int x=0;x<11;x++){
            if (bookList[x] instanceof Textbook){
                String newCourse = ((Textbook) bookList[x]).getCourse();
                String courseName = courseList[n];
                if(newCourse.equals(courseName)){
                    bookPrice = ((Textbook) bookList[x]).retailPrice();
                    System.out.printf("%-10s bbbsd  %-10s  %-10s  %-10s \n",
                            ((Textbook) bookList[x]).getCourse(),((Textbook) bookList[x]).getTitle(),
                            ((Textbook) bookList[x]).getAuthor(),fmt.format(bookPrice));
                    retailSum = retailSum + bookPrice;

                }
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.printf("Sum of retail book Prices: %-40s\n", fmt.format(retailSum));
```

This is the output I get

> List of textbooks: 
>   Sum of retail book Prices: $0.00

Comment: Well you haven't shown where `bookList` is initialized, which makes it hard to help you. Please provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Also, beware that `newCourse.equals(courseName)` is case sensitive comparison.  You could use `newCourse.equalsIgnoreCase(courseName)` is case is not a requirement

Comment: What Jon Skeet is saying is, he thinks that `bookList[x] instanceof Textbook` might be `false`

Comment: You need to debug your code and check the values within the bookList array after the do while loop.

Comment: It is still not a complete example as we don't know the contents of books.txt. You should use a debugger to check that `bookList []` contains what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would work if your `books.txt` file were as the code expects:

**books.txt**

```
TextBook
Title1 Author1 1 1 Course1
TradeBook
Title2 Author2 2 2 Course2
TextBook
Title3 Author3 3 3 Course3
```

I ran your program with the above books.txt file and it behaved exactly like I'd expect.